# How to save Text Field Values to ".txt" in the same hosting

Tags: javascript, html, text, hosting, textfield

I would like to know how to store the values of the text fields in a text file ".txt" on the same hosting server. If possible with some number to avoid overwriting any of the files.

**HTML Page**

[image]

**Output in Hosting**

[image]

**HTML Code...**

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Login</title>

<style type="text/css"></style></head><body><center>

<h1>Your Name</h1>

</center>

<center>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="age" placeholder="Your Age">
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" id="check" value="Login" onclick="clicked()">
</center>

<script type="text/JavaScript" src="log.php"></script>

</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: You'll need some sort of server-side code, like PHP, to do this. Take a look at PHP's `file_put_contents`, but be *very* aware that letting users upload files to your hosting can have **very significant** security risks.

Comment: (and if you're storing form data like this, consider a database instead of a bunch of text files...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please **DONT** use this but if you **NEED** to;

Here is a PHP script to achieve the function required; it'll take the input via GET, although that's easily changed to POST if needed

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$age = $_GET['age'];

$log = 'log.txt';
$IP = getenv ('REMOTE_ADDR');

if (!file_exists ($log)) {
    echo "Error: $log does not exist.";
    exit;
}

$h = fopen ($log, 'a');
fwrite($h, "
$IP:$name:$age");
fclose($h);


?>
```

make a file called, log.txt before running or rename `$log =` to whatever file you need.

You can remove `$IP:` if you don't want to log the visitors ip too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, here are the files, how do I proceed now?
Image: https://imgur.com/Lyzhkv4.png
How do I call PHP when I press the submit button?

Comment: What does the HTML look like for your form?

Comment: I updated the post, I inserted the HTML of the page.

Comment: okay, get rid of that "log.php" script tag, that's not how this works;
Your form should look like this https://pastebin.com/hmaZBum7

Comment: If you have a look https://www.w3schools.com/html/ you can learn some of the fundamental basics of HTML, that might help you alot with this 

Comment: Oops... I forgot to add name attributes to that HTML!! Here's an updated one https://pastebin.com/de0xBg8q

Comment: I just started studying for a few weeks. The HTML page is giving 502 Bad Gateway Error: https://imgur.com/fMnpqmR.png